# Heroku is not setting php version from my composer file

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I did follow the guide to deploy a php project in `heroku` i am trying to deploy a `laravel 5.6` project, i did everything it says to do and my `composer` looks like this

```
{
    "name": "My project",
    "description": "my project description.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
}
```

as you can see i am setting `php ^7.1.0` but when i make push to `heroku` i see this

```
 Installing platform packages...
 remote:        - php (7.2.9)
 remote:        - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
 remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
 remote:        - apache (2.4.34)
```

what i want is to use php 7.1. What am i missing? do i have to add the php in another require?

Comment: i want it to run on php 7.1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^7.1.0` will support any version equal to or above 7.1.0 until 8.0.0.  If you want only 7.1 minor versions, use `7.1.*`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-

Comment: did not knew that, thnks